# Undefined symbols argp_parse and arpg_usage when installing rng-tools on OSX

Tags: c, macos, unix, gcc, argparse

I am currently trying to install `rng-tools` on OSX, as I have a specific need for it to speed up a certain simulator that I am currently using. At first, I faced the problem of not having `argp`, so I installed `argp-standalone` from `Homebrew`. However, I still receive the following error message when trying to `make rng-tools`:

```
gcc  -g -O2   -o rngtest stats.o rngtest.o librngd.a 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_argp_parse", referenced from:
      _main in rngtest.o
  "_argp_usage", referenced from:
      _parse_opt in rngtest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [rngtest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked `/usr/local/include/argp.h` and it does seem to contain the correct function definitions referenced in `rngtest.c`, so any thoughts on what might be the problem?

Comment: `argp.h` does not contain the function definitions, just the declarations.  You probably just need to add `-l` and `-L` flags so the linker can find the definitions.

Comment: Yup, that fixed the problem. However, isn't there a way to automate such a process? I mean since both the declarations and definitions are present, why can't gcc just find them?

Comment: It looks in certain locations for libraries.  Usually, /usr/local/lib is not one of them.  You need to either configure your system so that the linker looks there, or you need to install the library in a directory that is in the search path.

Answer (score 2):

I just needed rngtest which I managed to compile on OSX using this https://github.com/fproulx/rngtest (which also needs brew install argp-standalone). I made that into a homebrew formula which can be obtained here: https://github.com/oderwat/homebrew-experiments