# Linking argp library for gcc on OSX

Tags: macos, gcc, linker

I am having pretty much the same problem as in this question

[Undefined symbols argp_parse and arpg_usage when installing rng-tools on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568389/undefined-symbols-argp-parse-and-arpg-usage-when-installing-rng-tools-on-osx)

but it's a different project. It seems the problem was solved by linking in argp, which I installed with homebrew. However, I can't link it properly. This is the error, where you can see how I've tried to link argp-standalone with -L.

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -DRESDIR=\"/usr/local/share/tsim\"
-g -O2 -L/usr/local/opt/argp-standalone/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXaw -lXt -lXmu -lX11 -lXext
-o tsim tsim-AddToggleWidget.o tsim-DialogPopup.o tsim-file.o tsim-resources.o tsim-timer.o
tsim-tsim.o tsim-bitmap.o tsim-DrawingPalette.o tsim-Graph.o tsim-sound.o tsim-train.o
tsim-BitmapDirectory.o tsim-errcheck.o tsim-pipe.o tsim-Sprite.o tsim-tsim_argp.o

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_argp_parse", referenced from:
      _parse in tsim-tsim_argp.o
  "_argp_usage", referenced from:
      _parse_opt in tsim-tsim_argp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [tsim] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: -L tells the compiler where to look for libraries, it does not link in any libraries. -l is for linking to libraries.

Comment: Ok, so I would both -L/usr/local/opt/argp-standalone/lib and -l/usr/local/opt/argp-standalone/lib/libargp.a then?